# List of Uninitialized Objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns

So here is my goal, I would like to instantiate an object based on a string and an integer. My current thought was this:

1) Create a list of possible objects
2) Each object has a static method that takes a string and integer and returns true, if what was passed matches the static members that object.
3) Then iterate over the list of possible objects, call the static function of that object if it returns true then instantiate that particular object:

pseudocode:

```
// Pseudo Definitions
class CoolObject
class CoolObject2: public CoolObject ....
class CoolObject3: public CoolObject ....

// List of Objects
std::list<CoolObject> list_of_possible_objects;
list_of_possible_objects.push_back(CoolObject);
list_of_possible_objects.push_back(CoolObject2);
list_of_possible_objects.push_back(CoolObject3);

// Inside of the matching function
for (std::list<CoolObject>::iterator it=list_of_possible_objects.begin(); it != list_of_possible_objects.end(); it++) {
    if(*it::is_cool_object(string, int)) {
        return *it(string1, string2); //Assume the constructor takes some objects that were passed into the function
    }
}
```

However, this seems like a dream since C++ does not allow to have objects that are not instantiated.

I am sure I can do this with some kinda map and a switch statement but this seemed lot more elegant in my head so I went for it first.

Is there any pattern out there that is similar to this, that I can follow? Or is there a way to make what I am asking be legal?

I would rather not maintain a huge map and I would rather just have a list of objects and ask each object if its the one and then instantiate, if having a huge map and a switch statement is the only way, thats fine. I thought maybe ask some gurus, if this is possible or is there a better way of doing it before giving up on this way.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is have a list of factories, rather than instances, yes?

Comment: despite what design or pattern, what is the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Make a list of `std::pair`. The first element of the pair is the test function, the second element is the constructor function. Then populate it with `{CoolObject::is_cool_object, CoolObject}`, `{CoolObject2::is_cool_object, CoolObject2}`, etc. The loop then calls the first function, and if it succeeds it calls the constructor.

Comment: Voted to close as **unclear**.

Comment: As stated (as I'm writing this comment) the question is nonsense: it does not make sense to create a list of uninitialized objects corresponding to each possible combination of a string and an integer. The actual issue might be anything

Comment: @kfsone yea after I wrote down my question and thought a bit more about it today, I kind of want a factory design. But just storing uninitliazed objects in an array as I have shown does not work, so thats where my problem comes from. I will try to read up on some factory design pattern see if I can find a way around.

Comment: @FirstStep my real problem is as I stated above in the first sentence sorry if it does not make sense. I would like to instantiate the right object, based on a string and integer given to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Store `std::optional<T>`, that's probably what you're looking for: basically just a flag to tell if the object is constructed and a reference to the object iff constructed. Note that you can't spare the flag, as you need to know whether to run the destructor or not.